# finish() not working properly sometimes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have written the following code to show a message box using textview and button. When the button clicks, activity should be finished. But this is working sometimes, not consistent. Sometimes it hangs. How to make it consistently working? Please help

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
private TextView mText;
private Button mOk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.msgbox);

    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    mText.setText(“Click ok to exit”);

    mOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    mOk.setOnClickListener(mOnOkClickListener);
}

private final OnClickListener mOnOkClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
};
```

}

On working conditions, onPause, onStop and onDestroy are called while clicking the ok button. While hanging, it calls only onPause and it hangs. How to make it working consistently?

Comment: While hanging, it calls only onPause and it hangs. ? and share onpouse code here

Comment: Do you have any code written in onPause?

Comment: no..i wrote this much code only

Comment: This happens on a specific device or on many? It's hard for me to believe that this is a platform issue.

Comment: What do you mean by hang? Does your App through an exception in LogCat or you mean it does not exit?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make your message with a `DialogFragment`.
Setting it up:

```
//imports you'll need to add:
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

//Activity that fires up your Dialog needs to be a FragmentActivity:        
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// ...

//class representing Dialog you want to show
public static class Dialog1 extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Click ok to close");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Button text", null);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Executing your dialog:

```
    DialogFragment df = new Dialog1();
    df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Of course you can create more complex dialogs with this method - we used only two methods from `AlertDialog.Builder`, but [it has much more to offer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).